# Can't save on the database but my validation is working

Tags: php, html, sql

Good day! I’m making a page where the students can update their profile. So I need a method of validation. YES my validation code is working, but it does not save in the database. And after she/he complete answering the fields that are required he will proceed to another page.

Here’s my code:

```
<?php
// First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session 
    require("common.php"); 

    // At the top of the page we check to see whether the user is logged in or not 
    if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 
    { 
        // If they are not, we redirect them to the login page. 
        header("Location: login.php"); 

        // Remember that this die statement is absolutely critical.  Without it, 
        // people can view your members-only content without logging in. 
        die("Redirecting to login.php"); 
    } 

    // Everything below this point in the file is secured by the login system 

    // We can display the user's username to them by reading it from the session array.  Remember that because 
    // a username is user submitted content we must use htmlentities on it before displaying it to the user.
    // Database Variables (edit with your own server information)

        $server = 'localhost';
        $user = 'root';
        $pass = '';
        $db = 'testing';

        // Connect to server and select databse.
        mysql_connect("$server", "$user", "$pass")or die("cannot connect"); 
        mysql_select_db("$db")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql ="SELECT * FROM users_info WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['user']['username']."' ";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}

    // define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $addressErr = $ageErr = $cellnoErr = $emailErr = $fathers_nameErr = $f_occupationErr = $mothers_nameErr = $m_occupationErr = "";
$name = $address = $age = $cellno = $telno = $email = $fathers_name = $f_occupation = $mothers_name = $m_occupation = "";

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$test=mysql_fetch_array($result);

if(!$result) 
        {
        die("Error: Data not found..");
        }       
                 $name = $test['name'];
                 $address = $test['address'];
                 $age = $test['age'];
                 $cellno = $test['cellno'];
                 $telno = $test['telno'];
                 $email = $test['email'];
                 $fathers_name = $test['fathers_name'];
                 $f_occupation = $test['f_occupation'];
                 $mothers_name = $test['mothers_name'];
                 $m_occupation = $test['m_occupation'];
}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
  if (empty($_POST["name"]))
    {$nameErr = "Name is required";}
  else
    {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
      {
      $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
      }
    }

  if (empty($_POST["address"]))
    {$addressErr = "Address is required";}
    else
     {$address =($_POST["address"]);}

  if (empty($_POST["age"]))
    {$ageErr = "Age is required";}
    else
     {$age = ($_POST["age"]);}

    if (empty($_POST["cellno"]))
    {$cellnoErr = "Cellphone Number is required";}
    else
     {$cellno = ($_POST["cellno"]);}

  if (empty($_POST["email"]))
    {$emailErr = "Email is required";}
  else
    {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address syntax is valid
    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
      {
      $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
      }
    }

  if (empty($_POST["fathers_name"]))
    {$fathers_nameErr = "Father's Name is required";}
    else
     {$fathers_name = ($_POST["fathers_name"]);}

  if (empty($_POST["f_occupation"]))
    {$f_occupationErr = "Father's Occupation is required";}
    else
     {$f_occupation = ($_POST["m_occupation"]);}

  if (empty($_POST["mothers_name"]))
    {$mothers_nameErr = "Mother's Name is required";}
    else
     {$mothers_name =($_POST["mothers_name"]);}

  if (empty($_POST["m_occupation"]))
    {$m_occupationErr = "Mother's Occupation is required";}
    else
     {$m_occupation =($_POST["m_occupation"]);}
}
function test_input($data)
{
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;

    mysql_query ("UPDATE `users_info` SET `name` ='$name', `address` ='$address',`age` ='$age', `cellno` ='$cellno' , `telno` ='$telno', `email` ='$email', `fathers_name` ='$fathers_name', `f_occupation` ='$f_occupation', `mothers_name` ='$mothers_name', `m_occupation` ='$m_occupation' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['user']['username']."' ") or die(mysql_error()); 

    header("Location: myprofile.php");          
}
?>
```

Comment: What about it isn't working?

Comment: I take it that `session_start();` is to be found inside `common.php`

Comment: Hello Fred, yes `session_start();` includes in common.php

Comment: Just glancing real quick-like, I don't see a form element named `mothers_name` I could go on and sure to find other missing named elements.

Comment: Why all those parentheses around $_POST[]? Anyway, looks like you aren't sanitizing the input.

Comment: You have one named form element but a whole bunch of POST variables. If that's not your full form, then post it.

Comment: Post your HTML form markup

Comment: Plus, from what I can tell `$_SESSION['user']` hasn't been assigned. You're just checking if it's empty. If you're checking to see if it's empty coming from another page, then we need to know. Otherwise, assign it. So far, this question falls into the ***"unclear what you're asking"*** category.

Comment: Hello! i'm sorry if i wasn't reply to all your comments, because my internet connection fail. Anyways, i edit my code above. My validation WORKS but it does not saved in the database..

Answer (score 0):

You assign the variables and then redirect the page, maybe you should put them in an session also in order to shown them in the form.